# Snowflake connector issue on python AWS

Tags: snowflake-connector

Getting this error from python snowflake connector on AWS:
ImportError: cannot import name 'NamedTuple' from 'typing_extensions'

Answer (score 1):

From snowflake support:

it appears to have popped up yesterday

pip install 'typing-extensions>=4.3.0'
should fix it

This fixed the issue